# Laravel blade @extends being overriden elsewhere

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

Working on an inherited Laravel project. Each template `@extends` a base layout template (there are about 4). But a specific template file is somehow extending the wrong base template (a particular base template: `base_one.blade.php`). When I rename `base_one.blade.php`. The template file in question starts extending the correct base template. It seems like my `@extends` statement is being overridden somewhere else. Please help. I have looked everywhere for similar problems without luck.

Comment: No one would know your file structure, file names or if they event exits or if you have any duplicate files based on your descriptive question. Oh, ya its  `@extends` BTW.

Comment: It's impossible for us to help you without any code. Did you do a recursive, line by line search in your project for keywords, like `base_one` and `Blade::extends`?

Comment: @score Yeah, I know; typo (obviously).

Comment: @Ohgodwhy The keyword search sounds like a good idea. I will try that. Sorry I can't really post code. There's a lot of code connected to a lot of code. Even if I posted some, there'd still be a lot more you can't see here (unless I zip and attach entire project!)

Answer (score 0):

So I had to empty the blade file and add content back in bits in other to isolate the problem. It turns out my template file was acting weird because of a blade output statement inside a `<script>` tag at the bottom of the file:

`var ids = {{ json_encode($ids) }};`

The child template starts malfunctioning (inheriting/extending a completely different layout template) when `$ids` is not set. So I replaced line with:

`var ids = {{ json_encode(isset($ids) ? $ids : []) }};`

And this is one (of many) example of Laravel gotchas. In plain PHP you'd get an error telling you `$ids` isn't set; in Laravel something goes south but you haven't a clue why. Such is life.